# EPFImporter from Itunes shows undefined symbol: _PyObject_NextNotImplemented after just installing and running

Tags: python, centos, itunes

I've just installed python on a new Centos 6.6 server so I can run EPFImporter from itunes. 
Then I run on commandline the command: `./EPFImporter/EPFImporter.py -D mysql itunes20141208`

I am not sure if this helps but these are versions installed on the server:
Python 2.6.6
Centos6.6
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

Did anyone encounter this error before?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/EPFImporter/EPFImporter.py", line 43, in <module>
    import EPFIngester
  File "/root/EPFImporter/EPFIngester.py", line 40, in <module>
    import psycopg2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so: undefined symbol: _PyObject_NextNotImplemented
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for responding. I did a ldd and I have the following result. Does the following make sense?

ldd  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff8bfd000)
libpq.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libpq.so.5 (0x00007fe1fb05c000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe1fae3f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe1faaaa000)
libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007fe1fa83e000)
libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007fe1fa45b000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007fe1fa216000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fe1f9fdf000)
libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007fe1f9d87000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe1fb4bd000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007fe1f9aa0000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007fe1f989c000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007fe1f9670000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe1f946b000)
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fe1f9255000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007fe1f904a000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007fe1f8e46000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fe1f8c2c000)
libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007fe1f89b3000)
liblber-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007fe1f87a3000)
libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007fe1f8589000)
libssl3.so => /usr/lib64/libssl3.so (0x00007fe1f834a000)
libsmime3.so => /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so (0x00007fe1f811d000)
libnss3.so => /usr/lib64/libnss3.so (0x00007fe1f7dde000)
libnssutil3.so => /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so (0x00007fe1f7bb2000)
libplds4.so => /lib64/libplds4.so (0x00007fe1f79ad000)
libplc4.so => /lib64/libplc4.so (0x00007fe1f77a8000)
libnspr4.so => /lib64/libnspr4.so (0x00007fe1f756a000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fe1f734a000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fe1f7142000)
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have mismatching libraries: If you look at the [psycopg documents](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html), it says:

> Note The libpq header files used to compile psycopg2 should match the
>   version of the library linked at runtime. If you get errors about
>   missing or mismatching libraries when importing psycopg2 check (e.g.
>   using ldd) if the module psycopg2/_psycopg.so is linked to the right
>   libpq.so.

Answer (score 0):

Reading http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html documents helped me fix the prob.
"yum install python-psycopg2" fixed it.